# Is it possible to change the color of individual splitlines in Apache ECharts for React gauge chart?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, echarts, gauge

I have a gauge chart where the progress bar indicator goes from 0 to 180 degrees, similarly to [this example](https://echarts.apache.org/examples/en/editor.html?c=gauge-progress).

What I want to do is have the splitline colors follow the color of progress bar. For instance, if the progress bar and pointer are at 50%, all splitlines until that point should be the same color as the progress bar, while the rest should be a default color.

I know that I can set options for the chart, however this only allows me to set the color of splitlines as a who. Is there a way to access them individually and color them based on some condition?

I've already tried providing a callback function that takes the value of the progress bar, but it seems like it doesn't work - all splitlines are then colored black, which I guess is a fallback color.